# Weka SVM taking too long to run

Tags: classification, weka, svm

I am running a SVM classification (LibSVM) on weka with 10-fold cross validation on a mac. I increased heap size and allocated ~6GB to it. But, when I check memory usage, it shows only ~2GB (at max) is used by weka GUIChooser (which i believe is the process name). My arff file is about 35MB large.

Classification runs forever and does not seem to complete. Although CPU usage is significant, it is not helping. Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using linear SVM or kernel SVM? Linear should be much faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, in both cases it is running very slow. I tried -Xmx2048 option while starting weka as well. I was running kernel SVM then changed to linear SVM, but no luck.

Comment: 10-fold CV is simply very costly because it has to do basically 10 times the work. Try to use a lower CV factor.